# Select in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table `X`

```
+----+----+
|num |word|
+----+----+
|1   |a   |
|2   |a   |
|3   |c   |
|1   |b   |
|2   |c   |
|3   |d   |
```

I want to select the `num` which has the word `a` but does not have the word
`c`.

Expected output

```
Num
----
1
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return the expected result:

```
select num
from x
where word in ('a', 'c')
group by num
having max(case when word = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Is the 'c' in your IN statement necessary? Wouldn't we just be interested in the distinct num values that have a (= 'a') and having max(...word = 'c'...) = 0?

Comment: @clesiemo3: I filter for both 'a' and 'c' because this reduces the number of rows to be processed in the GROUP BY and  the question didn't care about other values. If you only filter for `word = 'a'` you will never get a 'c' to be processed in HAVING.

Comment: Ah gotcha. That makes sense. I figured there was a reason but my brain wasn't processing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select num
from your_table
group by num
having sum(case when word = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when word = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solutions using `NOT EXISTS` and `MINUS`:

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT num from X x1 WHERE word = 'a' 
not exists (SELECT num FROM X x2 WHERE x2.num = x1.num and word = 'c');
```

Using `MINUS`

```
SELECT num from X WHERE word = 'a' 
minus
SELECT num FROM X WHERE word = 'c';
```

Comment: From performance point of view, you are scanning the table twice, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B: Depending on the actual data (and indexes) this might still be faster than concatenation all row using LISTAGG and then filter using LIKE :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - If you have appropriate indexes on `word`, it should only do seeks which is faster.

Comment: @dnoeth Where did I say LISTAGG would be faster, I just said that the above queries in the answer is scanning the table twice.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: "From performance point of view, you are scanning the table twice, which is not a good idea." -> this suggest, that it's not performant. Your own solution uses LISTAGG, so I assumed you think this is more efficient than this solution.

Comment: @dnoeth No odds, but I hope you understand that I never ever said that string aggregation would be faster. I really want to know what interested you here? I bet you prove that 2 table scans are better in terms of performance in Oracle. Would you please throw some light. And please mind, we are talking about Oracle database. I would be happy to be proved wrong :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB: If a solution is better or not depends on data and indexing (and this is independent of the DBMS), properly indexed there's no scan. Btw, I usually prefer to access a table only once, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, one way is **string aggregation**. For example **LISTAGG**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 num, 'a' word FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,   'a' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3,   'c' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1,   'b' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2,   'c' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 3,   'd' FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT num FROM(
 10  SELECT num, LISTAGG(word, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY num) str
 11  FROM DATA
 12  GROUP BY num
 13  )
 14  WHERE str LIKE '%a%'
 15  AND str NOT LIKE '%c%';

       NUM
----------
         1

SQL>
```

In your actual table, use:

```
SELECT num FROM(
SELECT num, LISTAGG(word, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY num) str
FROM your_table
GROUP BY num
)
WHERE str LIKE '%a%'
AND str NOT LIKE '%c%';
```